# Autorun python script from python

Tags: python, python-2.7, scheduled-tasks

I wrote a python script that downloads a random picture from [APOD](http://apod.nasa.gov/apod/astropix.html). I want to be able to specify the update frequency in python and have python automatically run the script. So the program would look something like this:

```
//first setup
print "how often should the background change in hours?"
updatefrequency = input()
schedule_autorun(updatefrequency)
//run each time
runprogram()
```

I've seen that people have used the windows task scheduler to auto run the program, but I would like to set it from python. I am running python 2.7 on Windows 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about the time module?

```
import time
timeinseconds = 100000
while(1):
    time.sleep(timeinseconds)
    runProgram()
```

If the time it takes to run the program exceeds your wait time, you can also call it as a separate process.

```
from subprocess import call
call(['python','runProgram.py'])
```

or subprocess.Popen

Comment: hmmmm maybe, How accurate is this, and how much resources does the script take up while its sleeping?

Comment: I'm not sure what to tell you. Resource-wise, it would take about as much as it would to just keep python running. Comparing it time-wise, I would assume it'd only be a real issue if your sleep time is realllllly small. I've never run any comparison tests with other methods.

Comment: Alright, well, I think what I will do is have Windows task manager run the script at login, and the time.sleep will handle it after that. Thanks